# How can I retrieve mail from an Exchange 2007 server?

Tags: email, exchange-server

I need to write an application that can read email and attachments from a mailbox in Exchange 2007. What is the best way to do this? Outlook Redemption works, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. Starting from POP3 or IMAP (as [indicated by Dominik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/136164/dominik-fretz)) to more powerful options such as the ones listed at [Exchange Development Technologies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa579177(EXCHG.80).aspx).

I would avoid starting new developments with APIs that are being phased out by Microsoft, so you may want to take a look at the [Exchange Server 2010's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa579177.aspx) version of the article above.

A safe bet would be to use [Exchange Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb204119(EXCHG.80).aspx) (a.k.a EWS). You should be able to program against it using any language capable of doing SOAP Web Services.

If you are programming against .Net Framework 3.5 or above and Exchange Server 2007 SP1 or above, you can use [EWS Managed API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633709(EXCHG.80).aspx) which is the client-side API for EWS and offers a much cleaner experience than the one provided by auto-generated web service proxies (via Add Web Reference menu item).

Answer (score 2):

You could simply us POP3 or IMAP to access the mails on the Exchange server.
Depending on your environment you would probably find libraries that provide POP3 or IMAP implementation.

Comment: This would require the Exchange Server to have the IMAP access set up (which I know some Exchange environments refuse to enable).

Answer (score 0):

Use Microsoft Exchange Server MAPI Editor (MFCMAPI) which is a great tool to retrieve MSG (or EML) files.

I personally use the cfexchangeConnection in coldfusion to reach out to mailboxes (as well as all other items in exchange)